# Writing a manuall (command line) triggered script to bulk change some DB values in Django?

Tags: django

I know that the best practice is to generally use these https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations, but I have been told that automatic migrations are risky and the powers that be want me to write a manual script that can be triggered manually on production instead.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?  Where would be the best place for it to live in the Django repo? How do I import everything I need? Anyone have an example?

Comment: Is it a one-time migration or something that needs to be done on a periodic basis? Data migrations are part of migrations framework and meant for one-time migrations needed after a schema change. For periodic tasks it is recommended to write a Custom Management Command.

Comment: @Selcuk one time, but they don't want it as part of the automated migration stuff.

Comment: A [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) is your best bet then. It will automatically import all the required Django stuff and all you have to import will be your own models (and other utilities that you might need). It is similar to writing a view.